# Xcode 8.3.2 build script - Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory

Tags: ios, swift3, xcodebuild, xcode8

I have a problem with xcode build script, hope you can help.

In older Xcode this script works well but now after upgraded the xcode always failed.

> configuration='Release'
>       provision="haithngn_release.mobileprovision"
>       identity="iPhone Distribution: HAITHNGN (TEAMID)"
>
> ```
> sdk="iphoneos"
> scheme="Mobile"
> configuration=$1
> version=$2
> build=$3
> output="$PWD/build/$scheme.$version.$build.$configuration.ipa"
>
> PLIST_PATH="./Mobile/Platforms/ios/Application/"
> PLIST_FILE="Info.plist"
>
> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $version" "$PLIST_PATH/$PLIST_FILE"
> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $version.$build" "$PLIST_PATH/$PLIST_FILE"
>
> echo "Cleaning up old build..."
> rm -Rf "$PWD/build/$configuration-$sdk"
>
> echo "Building $scheme, using $configuration configuration, provisioning = $provision"
>
> xcodebuild -sdk "$sdk" -scheme "$scheme" -configuration "$configuration" clean OBJROOT="$PWD/build" SYMROOT="$PWD/build" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
> xcodebuild -sdk "$sdk" -scheme "$scheme" -configuration "$configuration" OBJROOT="$PWD/build" SYMROOT="$PWD/build" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$identity"
> xcodebuild -exportArchive -sdk "$sdk" "$PWD/build/$configuration-$sdk/$scheme.app" "$PWD/build/$configuration-$sdk/$scheme.ipa" "$provision"
> cp "$PWD/build/$configuration-$sdk/$scheme.ipa" "$output"
> ```

Terminal Logs:

> xcodebuild: error: The flag -exportPath is required when specifying
>   -exportArchive. xcodebuild: error: The flag -exportOptionsPlist is required when specifying -exportArchive. xcodebuild: error: The flag
>   -archivePath is required when specifying -exportArchive.

XCode version 8.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Xcode 8.3, you should use `xcodebuild -exportArchive` instead of `xcrun` (see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500558/packageapplication-stopped-working-with-os-x-10-10-yosemite-today)) or apparently, just zipping the App works as well (see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094380/whats-the-replacement-for-xcodes-packageapplication)).

Otherwise, you might want to use [Fastlane Gym](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/gym#readme).

Comment: Thank you for your idea,
I have adjust
xcodebuild -exportArchive -sdk "$sdk" "$PWD/build/$configuration-$sdk/$scheme.app" "$PWD/build/$configuration-$sdk/$scheme.ipa" "$provision"

build success but still some problem

xcodebuild: error: The flag -exportPath is required when specifying -exportArchive.
xcodebuild: error: The flag -exportOptionsPlist is required when specifying -exportArchive.
xcodebuild: error: The flag -archivePath is required when specifying -exportArchive.

Comment: Yes, you have to provide few additional flags now. Have a look at this: http://subathrathanabalan.com/2016/01/07/building-ipa-export-archive/

Comment: ** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED ** then ** EXPORT FAILED **
Errors={
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8928e72ba0; name="iPhone Distribution: HAITHNGN (TEAMID)', hash='sssssss', serialNumber='ssssssss', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4, issueDate='2017-05-25 02:35:35 +0000''>" =     {
        "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7f8928ea6360 '......
IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=10 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\