# Xcode 6.1 - ressource-rules.plist error with Cordova app project

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm actually trying to sign an iOS Cordova application.
The project was created with the following configuration :

- OS X 10.9.4
- Xcode 5.1
- Cordova 3.6

Today, my configuration is :

- OS X 10.10
- Xcode 6.1.1
- Cordova 4.1.2

Every time I try to sign the application, I get this error :

```
error: /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,
resource-rules --sign AUDIPOG (94QQ6PT92C) --resource-rules=/var/folders/lm
/kf2d3xk95f3330_f0xn24xmm0000gn/T/x2pZphou5t/Payload/AUDiPOG.app/
ResourceRules.plist /var/folders/lm/kf2d3xk95f3330_f0xn24xmm0000gn/T
/x2pZphou5t/Payload/AUDiPOG.app failed with error 1. Output: Warning: 
usage of --preserve-metadata with 
option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!
/var/folders/lm/kf2d3xk95f3330_f0xn24xmm0000gn/T/x2pZphou5t/Payload/
AUDiPOG.app/ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources
```

I run through some posts referring the same error, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459911/resource-rules-has-been-deprecated-in-mac-os-x-10-10?answertab=votes#tab-top), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488077/ios-ipa-codesign-on-xcode-6-1-yosemite), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464577/jenkins-vs-xcode-plugin-codesign-troubles), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138525/xcode-sharing-app-packageapplication-failed-with-exit-code-1/26261751#26261751), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497863/xcode-6-1-error-while-building-ipa-using-testflight-app) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459911/resource-rules-has-been-deprecated-in-mac-os-x-10-10/26485381#26485381)

They all offer the same fix :

```
$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist
```

Put this line at this location :

```
project > Targets > Select your target > Build Settings > Code Signing Resource Rules Path
```

I tried this fix... but it's not working.

I also tried : Clean my project, Force close Xcode and redo the fix, etc...

Nothing seems to work.

Someone know what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it ! I went back to Xcode 6.0.1