# Xcode command line build error

Tags: xcode, ant, xcode6, osx-yosemite, ios8.1

I am trying to archive my Xcode project from command line terminal using **xcodebuild** and **xcrun**. To be clear enough, I am doing that from ANT script.

```
<target name="build">

<exec executable="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild">
<arg value="-project"/>
<arg value="${local.projectPath}/${app.id}.xcodeproj"/>
<arg value="-scheme"/>
<arg value="${scheme}"/>
<arg value="-configuration"/>
<arg value="${configuration}"/>
<arg value="clean"/>
<arg value="build"/>
</exec>

</target>

<target name="package" depends="build">

<exec executable="xcrun">
<arg value="-sdk"/>
<arg value="iphoneos"/>
<arg value="PackageApplication"/>
<arg value="-v"/>
<arg value="${local.projectPath}/DerivedData/dist/${app.id}/Build/Products/${configuration}-iphoneos/${app.id}.app"/>
<arg value="-o"/>
<arg value="${local.ipaPath}/${app.id}.${appVersion}.b${buildNumber}.${environment}.ipa"/>
<arg value="--sign"/>
<arg value="iPhone Distribution: ${developerName}"/>
<arg value="--embed"/>
<arg value="${provisioningProfile}"/>
</exec>
```

After upgrading to 6.1 version, I am getting below error.

**/var/folders/hk/bg4j097j1kncryfrplv4b3bw0000gp/T/f3UZyfiqbS/Payload/MyApp.app/ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources**

Then, I found the below post.

[Xcode - Sharing app - PackageApplication failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138525/xcode-sharing-app-packageapplication-failed-with-exit-code-1/7919137#7919137)

According to that, I added the below in code signing section of build settings.

**Code Signing Resource Rules Path: $(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist**

That solved my issue though the warning still persisted. But I came across the Apple's technical note @ https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG401 which states that:

*"Systems before OS X Mavericks documented a signing feature (--resource-rules) to control which files in a bundle should be sealed by a code signature. This feature has been obsoleted for Mavericks. Code signatures made in Mavericks and later always seal all files in a bundle; there is no need to specify this explicitly any more. **This also means that the Code Signing Resource Rules Path build setting in Xcode should no longer be used and should be left blank**.
It is thus no longer possible to exclude parts of a bundle from the signature. Bundles should be treated as read-only once they have been signed."*

I am totally confused now. If I leave the field blank, I am getting error. And if I include, it violates Apple's guidelines. What should I do now? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this question: 
[Xcode - Sharing app - PackageApplication failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138525/xcode-sharing-app-packageapplication-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Apple states that "there is no need..." it's like being ignored, but you are not violating any rule, I think other platforms that compile this projects that are still taking that field into account, so if you have problems compiling or archiving just add `$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist` to **Code Signing Resource Rules Path** and try again.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that I can still add this in my build settings? What is actually violating any rule?

Comment: You can write it, and you are not "violating" any rule. Apple says "there is no need to specify", where I understand that you can write or not, but if you do, nothing is going to happen.